# Is there a way to set the width of a child div to 100% of the browser?

Tags: jquery, css, dotnetnuke

Is there a way to set the `width` of a `child div` to `100%` of the browser, not 100% of the `parent div`?
`Position: fixed` is the only way I have found but this is part of a nav so that will not work. Basically it is a `dropdown` menu and the `sub-nav` needs to span 100% of the browser's width.
Preferably with just css. I am dealing with a `DNN nav` and I can't modify the script itself.
The script is in jQuery so if there is a way to modify it on the document I may be able to do that.

Here is the menu structure

```html
<div id="dnnStandardMenu">
  <ul class="dnnNav">
    <li data-page-id="676387" class="root mi mi0 sel first" style="width: 126px;"><a href="/Default.aspx?tabid=676387" target="" class="txt">Home</a></li>
    <li data-page-id="914191" class="root mi mi0" style="width: 144px;"><a href="/Default.aspx?tabid=914191" target="" class="txt">Culture</a></li>
    <li data-page-id="914192" class="root mi mi0" style="width: 145px;"><a href="/Default.aspx?tabid=914192" target="" class="txt">Contact</a></li>
    <li data-page-id="914193" class="root mi mi0" style="width: 132px;"><a href="/Default.aspx?tabid=914193" target="" class="txt">Coach</a></li>
    <li data-page-id="914194" class="root mi mi0 haschild" style="width: 138px;"><a href="/Default.aspx?tabid=914194" target="" class="txt">REFEREE</a><ul class="m m0">

      <li class="col"><ul class="col1"><li data-page-id="914196" class="mi mi1 first"><a href="/Default.aspx?tabid=914196" target="" class="txt"><span class="icn no-icn"></span>Online Training</a></li><li data-page-id="914198" class="mi mi1 last"><a href="/Default.aspx?tabid=914198" target="" class="txt"><span class="icn no-icn"></span>Referee Supplies</a></li></ul></li><li class="col"><ul class="col2"><li data-page-id="914197" class="mi mi1"><a href="/Default.aspx?tabid=914197" target="" class="txt"><span class="icn no-icn"></span>SAY vs. USSF Rule Differences</a></li></ul></li><li class="col"><ul class="col3"><li data-page-id="914199" class="mi mi1"><a href="/Default.aspx?tabid=914199" target="" class="txt"><span class="icn no-icn"></span>Qualifications</a></li></ul></li></ul>
    </li>
    <li data-page-id="914205" class="root mi mi0" style="width: 138px;"><a href="/Default.aspx?tabid=914205" target="" class="txt">sadmin</a></li>
    <li data-page-id="7" class="root mi mi0 haschild last" style="width: 123px;"><span class="txt">Host</span><ul class="m m0" style="visibility: visible; left: -55px; width: 752px; right: auto; display: none;">
      <li class="col" style="height: 260px;"><ul class="col1"><li data-page-id="187309" class="mi mi1 first"><a href="/Default.aspx?tabid=187309&amp;portalid=9048" target="" class="txt"><span class="icn no-icn"></span>Health Monitor</a></li><li data-page-id="252866" class="mi mi1"><a href="/Default.aspx?tabid=252866&amp;portalid=9048" target="" class="txt"><span class="icn no-icn"></span>Host Alerts</a></li><li data-page-id="116842" class="mi mi1"><a href="/Default.aspx?tabid=116842&amp;portalid=9048" target="" class="txt"><span class="icn no-icn"></span>Payment Sync</a></li><li data-page-id="85608" class="mi mi1"><a href="/Default.aspx?tabid=85608&amp;portalid=9048" target="" class="txt"><span class="icn no-icn"></span>Report Wizard 2.0</a></li><li data-page-id="19" class="mi mi1"><a href="/Default.aspx?tabid=19&amp;portalid=9048" target="" class="txt"><span class="icn no-icn"></span>File Manager</a></li><li data-page-id="83444" class="mi mi1"><a href="/Default.aspx?tabid=83444&amp;portalid=9048" target="" class="txt"><span class="icn no-icn"></span>Lists</a></li><li data-page-id="112125" class="mi mi1"><a href="/Default.aspx?tabid=112125&amp;portalid=9048" target="" class="txt"><span class="icn no-icn"></span>Extensions</a></li><li data-page-id="545857" class="mi mi1 last"><a href="/Default.aspx?tabid=545857&amp;portalid=9048" target="" class="txt"><span class="icn no-icn"></span>HTML Editor Manager</a></li></ul></li><li class="col" style="height: 260px;"><ul class="col2"><li data-page-id="16" class="mi mi1"><a href="/Default.aspx?tabid=16&amp;portalid=9048" target="" class="txt"><span class="icn no-icn"></span>Host Settings</a></li><li data-page-id="181364" class="mi mi1"><a href="/Default.aspx?tabid=181364&amp;portalid=9048" target="" class="txt"><span class="icn no-icn"></span>Bulk Email</a></li><li data-page-id="92782" class="mi mi1"><a href="/Default.aspx?tabid=92782&amp;portalid=9048" target="" class="txt"><span class="icn no-icn"></span>Daily Payment Summary</a></li><li data-page-id="129517" class="mi mi1"><span class="txt"><span class="icn no-icn"></span>Store</span><ul class="m m1">
            <li data-page-id="129518" class="mi mi2 first"><a href="/Default.aspx?tabid=129518&amp;portalid=9048" target="" class="txt"><span class="icn no-icn"></span>Royalty Invoices</a></li>
            <li data-page-id="129519" class="mi mi2"><a href="/Default.aspx?tabid=129519&amp;portalid=9048" target="" class="txt"><span class="icn no-icn"></span>Royalty Report - Current Period</a></li>
            <li data-page-id="149762" class="mi mi2"><a href="/Default.aspx?tabid=149762&amp;portalid=9048" target="" class="txt"><span class="icn no-icn"></span>Product Sales Report</a></li>
            <li data-page-id="152479" class="mi mi2"><a href="/Default.aspx?tabid=152479&amp;portalid=9048" target="" class="txt"><span class="icn no-icn"></span>Product Sales Origin Report</a></li>
            <li data-page-id="157549" class="mi mi2"><a href="/Default.aspx?tabid=157549&amp;portalid=9048" target="" class="txt"><span class="icn no-icn"></span>Portal Products</a></li>
            <li data-page-id="157550" class="mi mi2 last"><a href="/Default.aspx?tabid=157550&amp;portalid=9048" target="" class="txt"><span class="icn no-icn"></span>Product Attribute Editor</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li><li data-page-id="21" class="mi mi1"><a href="/Default.aspx?tabid=21&amp;portalid=9048" target="" class="txt"><span class="icn no-icn"></span>SQL</a></li><li data-page-id="83445" class="mi mi1"><a href="/Default.aspx?tabid=83445&amp;portalid=9048" target="" class="txt"><span class="icn no-icn"></span>Superuser Accounts</a></li><li data-page-id="113401" class="mi mi1"><a href="/Default.aspx?tabid=113401&amp;portalid=9048" target="" class="txt"><span class="icn no-icn"></span>Skins</a></li></ul></li><li class="col last" style="height: 260px;"><ul class="col3"><li data-page-id="308159" class="mi mi1"><a href="/Default.aspx?tabid=308159&amp;portalid=9048" target="" class="txt"><span class="icn no-icn"></span>Order Summary</a></li><li data-page-id="17" class="mi mi1"><a href="/Default.aspx?tabid=17&amp;portalid=9048" target="" class="txt"><span class="icn no-icn"></span>Site Management</a></li><li data-page-id="93184" class="mi mi1"><a href="/Default.aspx?tabid=93184&amp;portalid=9048" target="" class="txt"><span class="icn no-icn"></span>Invoice Summary</a></li><li data-page-id="157553" class="mi mi1"><a href="/Default.aspx?tabid=157553&amp;portalid=9048" target="" class="txt"><span class="icn no-icn"></span>AT</a><ul class="m m1">
            <li data-page-id="157557" class="mi mi2 first"><a href="/Default.aspx?tabid=157557&amp;portalid=9048" target="" class="txt"><span class="icn no-icn"></span>Template Manager</a></li>
            <li data-page-id="157558" class="mi mi2 last"><a href="/Default.aspx?tabid=157558&amp;portalid=9048" target="" class="txt"><span class="icn no-icn"></span>Email Template Manager</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li><li data-page-id="3810" class="mi mi1"><a href="/Default.aspx?tabid=3810&amp;portalid=9048" target="" class="txt"><span class="icn no-icn"></span>Schedule</a></li><li data-page-id="112124" class="mi mi1"><a href="/Default.aspx?tabid=112124&amp;portalid=9048" target="" class="txt"><span class="icn no-icn"></span>Dashboard</a></li><li data-page-id="545856" class="mi mi1"><a href="/Default.aspx?tabid=545856&amp;portalid=9048" target="" class="txt"><span class="icn no-icn"></span>Configuration Manager</a></li></ul></li></ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Post some code please

Comment: it's only possible if all of the parent nodes are statically positioned.

Comment: Set `position: relative` on the parent and `position: absolute` on the child (sub-nav). Then position with `left` and `top`.

Comment: Have you tried using vw for this?

Comment: i'm guessing your subnav is a `ul` in an `li`.  If so, make the ul subnav absolute, for the li it is within, don't position that, and for the parent ul of that afore mentioned li, make that relative with a width of 100%

Comment: All these I have tried. one issue is DNN automatically sets the width of the ul depending on the menu items. positioning top and left would work if there was only one subnav off the main nav since they all get the same class it wouldn't look right, and the same with vw.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Simply set `width: 100vw`, where `vw` is the 1/100th of the viewport width. If that is being overridden, just use `!important` next to it.

Comment: That works but the position of the div still stays below the parent <li> so the width expands past the documents width. Setting left: 0, sets it to the parent, not the browser. I can't say left: -1200px because the nav has a couple subnavs and there positions would not be correct then.

Comment: @user1757641 make sure the parent has no position attribute. If that can't be avoided, use `left: calc(a - b)` to position it, substituting half the parents width for `a` and half the child's width for `b`. If that still doesn't work, use `position: fixed` as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not this most elegant solution, but it is the one i'm going with until I find a better solution.

I set position to fixed, and added this jQuery

```js
<script>
$(document).scroll(function(){
 if($(this).scrollTop() > 50){
  $('.say-child #dnnStandardMenu .root .m0').css({"display" : "none", "top" : "auto"});
 }
  if($(this).scrollTop() > 75){
  $('.say-child #dnnStandardMenu .root .m0').css({"top" : "148px"});
 } 
  if($(this).scrollTop() > 100){
  $('.say-child #dnnStandardMenu .root .m0').css({"top" : "48px"});
 }
});
</script>
```